# Function overloading, integer types and std::size_t on 64-bit systems

Tags: c++11, overloading, size-t

The following code compiles fine on with GCC 4.8.5 and Clang 3.9.1 on my CentOS system, but does not compile with anything (GCC, Clang) on my MacOS system. They are both 64-bit systems. I guess that it comes from the different standard library used by those systems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

std::int32_t f(std::int32_t a) { return 0; }
std::uint32_t f(std::uint32_t a) { return 1; }
std::int64_t f(std::int64_t a) { return 2; }
std::uint64_t f(std::uint64_t a) { return 3; }

int main() {
  const std::size_t n = 0;

  std::cout << f(n) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

On MacOS, it complains about ambiguous overloading. I am surprised as I thought that `std::size_t` and `std::uint64_t` are the same on 64-bit systems.

```
>> clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
main.cpp:12:16: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
std::cout << f(n) << std::endl;
             ^
main.cpp:4:14: note: candidate function
std::int32_t f(std::int32_t a) { return 0; }
             ^
main.cpp:5:15: note: candidate function
std::uint32_t f(std::uint32_t a) { return 1; }
              ^
main.cpp:6:14: note: candidate function
std::int64_t f(std::int64_t a) { return 2; }
             ^
main.cpp:7:15: note: candidate function
std::uint64_t f(std::uint64_t a) { return 3; }
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Even though this example looks stupid, I really need to overload `f()` for signed/unsigned and 32/64-bit integers in my real application and their behaviour must depend on the size of the integer as I am playing with bits. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you think that `std::size_t` should exactly match one of those integer types?  All you know is that it's a typedef of *some unsigned integer type* and that it's what you get when you use `sizeof`, `sizeof...` or `alignof` operators.

Comment: @Toby It turns out that `std::size_t` is an unsigned integer (the standard says so) and is 64-bit on both of those platforms (because I have tested it). I am just surprised that 2 integer types of the same size and the same signess could be different. I have just discovered this week that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three different types but I thought that this strange behavior occurred only with `char` types.

Comment: @Toby What if I want to define my function for `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long` and `std::size_t` knowing that I have some C-style functions `f_unsigned`, `f_unsigned_long`, `f_unsigned_long_long`? Which one should I define so that I don't define my function twice for the same type. Is there even a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

*Simple answer:* do not call `f` with `std::size_t` - call it with one of the exact types accepted by `f`.

---

*Alternative answer*: you only care about *signedness* and *bit count*. Use `std::enable_if` with all possible combinations:

```
template <typename T, bool Signed, int Size>
using enable_if_sd = 
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_signed<T>{} == Signed && sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT == Size
    >::type;

template <typename T>
void f(T, enable_if_sd<T, true, 32>* = nullptr) 
{
    std::cout << "signed 32-bit\n";
}

template <typename T>
void f(T, enable_if_sd<T, true, 64>* = nullptr) 
{
    std::cout << "signed 64-bit\n";
}

template <typename T>
void f(T, enable_if_sd<T, false, 32>* = nullptr) 
{
    std::cout << "unsigned 32-bit\n";
}

template <typename T>
void f(T, enable_if_sd<T, false, 64>* = nullptr) 
{
    std::cout << "unsigned 32-bit\n";
}
```

[**coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e741a8da0fc78213)

Comment: It looks complicated. Don't you think that there is a simpler way?

Comment: @InsideLoop: I'll think about it. Regardless, does it solve your issue?